# calling create_superuser and create_user function in abstractuser in DRF

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-custom-user

I have customuser model which inherits the Abstratuser from Django. However, I didn't understand the create_user and create_superuser. For eg when is the create_user function is called and when the create_superuser function is called.

The model looks like this.

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self,first_name,last_name,email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The email must be set")
        first_name = first_name.capitalize()
        last_name = last_name.capitalize()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, **extra_fields
        )
        #user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name,last_name,email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(first_name,last_name,email, password, **extra_fields)


ROLE = (('admin','ADMIN'),('manager','MANAGER'),('staff','STAFF'))
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ROLE, default='staff')
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

For eg for other regular models like Contacts, we don't write create_contact function inside the model rather we create a post api and write logic inside view and serializer that creates a contact object. But why in CustomUser why we have to create functions explicitly although we again  write creating a user logic inside register view. Also, is there any difference using AbstractUser and AbstractBase user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you closely inspect the ***`create_user_XYZ(...)`*** methods, you will find that all those methods are creating the `User` (or `YourCustomModel`) instances. These methods are nicely separated as they are intended. For example, `create_superuser(...)` will create a superuser and `create_user()` will create a normal instance.

Apart from that, when it comes to ***auth models***, we need to set the password, which shouldn't be stored in plain text rather than it must be hashed before saves into DB. So, these `create_XYZ` methods also handle some extra logic for us.

Comment: so create_super_user is called when we run py manage.py create superuser and create_user is called from the view of the registration api?? Is that it?

Comment: do you know about pusher in django to send the notifications
do you have any resource online regarding that?? Sorry, it is out of context, but I need it urgently.

Comment: When we run `python  manage.py createsuperuser` command, Django internally calls the  **`create_superuser(...)`** method of the ***model manager of auth user class***. We can also, use the same (almost) everywhere in the Django project.